# find OS and licensed software for EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to figure out the OS and licensed software of an AWS ec2 instance by using API (specifically python's boto3 but if the solution comes from another SDK, that's fine by me).

I naturally tried using describe instances:

```
client = session.client('ec2')
ec2.describe_instances()
```

But the data is not there. I couldn't find it by using the `resource` api:

```
ec2 = session.resource('ec2')
for instance in ec2.instances.all():
   // I ran dir(instance) here just to see what's going on.
```

I searched through the documentation but couldn't find how to retrieve this information. I highly doubt it can't be found as Amazon uses this information for pricing and this info exists in the pricing API (which I would imagine be useless unless the corresponding data could be retrieved).

Answer (score 2):

Get the "ImageId" ami id for the ec2 via a describe_instances() call.

Then look up the ami with a "describe-images" call ie

```
$ aws --region eu-west-1  ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-4ac6653d
{
    "Images": [
        {
            "ProductCodes": [
                {
                    "ProductCodeId": "aacglxeowvn5hy8sznltowyqe", 
                    "ProductCodeType": "marketplace"
                }
            ], 
            "Name": "CentOS 6 x86_64 (2014_09_29) EBS pv-1-adc4348e-1dc3-41df-b833-e86ba57a33d6-ami-809020e8.2", 
            "VirtualizationType": "paravirtual", 
            "Hypervisor": "xen", 
            "ImageOwnerAlias": "aws-marketplace", 
            "ImageId": "ami-4ac6653d", 
            "RootDeviceType": "ebs", 
            "State": "available", 
            "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                {
                    "DeviceName": "/dev/sda", 
                    "Ebs": {
                        "DeleteOnTermination": false, 
                        "SnapshotId": "snap-8a6c3e70", 
                        "VolumeSize": 8, 
                        "VolumeType": "standard", 
                        "Encrypted": false
                    }
                }
            ], 
            "Architecture": "x86_64", 
            "ImageLocation": "aws-marketplace/CentOS 6 x86_64 (2014_09_29) EBS pv-1-adc4348e-1dc3-41df-b833-e86ba57a33d6-ami-809020e8.2", 
            "KernelId": "aki-52a34525", 
            "OwnerId": "679593333241", 
            "RootDeviceName": "/dev/sda", 
            "CreationDate": "2014-10-02T20:01:16.000Z", 
            "Public": true, 
            "ImageType": "machine", 
            "Description": "CentOS 6 x86_64 (2014_09_29) EBS PV-1"
        }
    ]
}
```

This will give information on the OS and if comes with licensed software

Finding 3rd party software that is installed on the running instances would require a different process, not sure how to generically do this

Answer (score 2):

Quick Answer : No, you cannot get OS and licensed software info directly from describe_instances() function.

Longer answer : such information need some sort of SNMP monitoring agent install in EVERY instances, this will impose too much complexity for any VM instances.

I make some effort trying to get all the details in boto3 script. 
After describe_instances(), loop the list from the result dictionary key ['Reservations'] to find AMI image id, then search information as above mentioned.

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.client("ec2")
instance_metas = ec2.describe_instances()
ami_list = list()
for each_instance in instance_metas['Reservations']: 
  ami_list.append(each_instance['Instances'][0]['ImageId'])

# next , query correspondence AMI info
ami_metas = ec2.describe_images(ImageIds=ami_list)
```

After inspecting the dict, I notice AWS DOESN'T store the OS info. The "Name" key is just abstract definition and may replaced by user.

If you want to grab the actual instance OS version, you can use the IP address given by ec2.client.describe_instances(), run a ssh script and take the instance OS version.

If you create instances from AWS AMI marketplace, all are licensed. Just counter check the AMI id.

Answer (score 0):

```
resp=ec2.describe_instances()
osname=resp['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['PlatformDetails']
print(osname)
```